# What's wrong in my code for setting up entity title in a Computed Field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have written inside a Computed Field's Computed Code section the following code:

```
<?php
//work if the node is new and there is no value for the field yet
if (empty($entity_field[0]['value'])) {

  do {
    //calculate a promotion code
    $new_promotion_code = strtoupper(substr(md5(rand(999, time())), 0, 5));

    //check db for conflicts
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle','gift')
      ->fieldCondition('field_gift_code', 'value', $new_promotion_code)
      ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
    $result = $query->count()->execute();
  } while($result > 0);

  //assign the field value
  $entity_field[0]['value'] = $new_promotion_code;

  //option#1
  //$entity->title[0]['value'] = $new_promotion_code;
  //option#2
  //$entity->title[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $new_promotion_code;

  //presave the node with attached fields (not sure if this is working)
  field_attach_presave($entity_type, $entity);
}
?>
```

This code works except the commented out section which includes two options for setting up same node's title. I am also not sure if `field_attach_presave()` works but I have no means to debug it and it just doesn't fail like `field_attach_update()`.

Using Auto Entity Label is also a solution but the token (`[node:field-gift-code:rawvalue]` or `[node:field-gift-code]`) for this field just prints `Array`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it all in the first box.

Use the Computed Code box to create a value for the field in $entity_field[0]['value'].

Then use the Display code box to do something with this value.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Can I just put

`$entity->title[0]['value'] = $entity_field_item['value'];`

into the display box?

Comment: Give it a try, but if you call drupal functions, you must do it in the Display code box.

Comment: Got a peaceful WSOD =)

Comment: Just tried to evaluate PHP in Auto Entity Label pattern: `<?php
print $entity->field_gift_code[0]['value'];
?>` gave nothing.