# How to display a computed field in an automatic node title?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I am trying to display something like "Field A - Field B" as a title for each content created on a Drupal 7 website.

The Field A is entered manually through Drupal standard form.

The Field B is computed with the module [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) and it depends on Field A value (this part works fine).

Now I would like to create automatically the node title on saving with [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel), using Token. (This is the new Automatic Nodetitles).

Unfortunately, using [node:field_a] - [node:field_b], the computed field B value is invisible. More, if you edit the node and save it a second time, the title is OK...

It seems like the field value calculation is made simultaneously with the title generation and thus this value can not be used to generate the title. Of course, I can not tell my client to save twice, we can not say it is user-friendly...

Is there another way to build this automatic title based on a computed field?

Related questions :

[How to Compute fields on the fly](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106165/how-to-compute-fields-on-the-fly)

[What's wrong in my code for setting up entity title in a Computed Field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68727/computed-field-setting-up-entity-title)

On the same subject on Drupal.org :

https://www.drupal.org/node/370850

Comment: What about setting up a rules event to set a data value for the node title using the event "after content is saved" ?

Comment: That could be a nice idea. I will try and return for feedback. Thanks

Comment: And it works! Do you want to write the answer so you can get credits on it?

Comment: Great news! I'll add it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting up a rules event to set a data value for the node title using the event "after content is saved" ?

This should work...

1. Set up a rule with the event "after content is saved".
2. Set up the action "set a data value"
3. Choose the title field, and use the tokens to set your value.